# Does this way protect my PHP Source?

Tags: php, encryption

*(sorry for my bad english!)*

To protect my php Source code, I want to encrypt only one file with ioncube(for example *function.php*), And then I want to call the encrypted file in other php files!
(other php files will be encrypted with mcrypt function.)

Please see the example:

function.php

```
<?php

// Only This file will be encrypted by the ionCube

  function simple_encrypt($text)
    {
$salt='whatever_you_want';
        return trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
    }

    function simple_decrypt($text)
    {
$salt='whatever_you_want';
        return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, base64_decode($text), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND)));
    }

function decrypt_and_run($text) {
eval (simple_decrypt($text));
}

?>
```

script1.php

```
<?php
include "function.php";
decrypt_and_run("Mz/PKIZDmo1/VW4BNXX2d+XQD2dx1aB9gnBj1hbGzVM=");
// Mz/PKIZDmo1/VW4BNXX2d+XQD2dx1aB9gnBj1hbGzVM=   ~   echo "hello world1!";
?>
```

script2.php

```
<?php
include "function.php";
decrypt_and_run("oD3R8wPlUujQEkJfyPvTJOKek7MjzAuGBn+PfyssjZ4=");
// oD3R8wPlUujQEkJfyPvTJOKek7MjzAuGBn+PfyssjZ4=   ~   echo "hello world2!";
?>
```

script3.php

```
<?php
include "function.php";
decrypt_and_run("vMef6WP9xm1nmsAYMSgxFRY2nhBPTNWog3rLOGhb69Y=");
// vMef6WP9xm1nmsAYMSgxFRY2nhBPTNWog3rLOGhb69Y=   ~   echo "hello world3!";
?>
```

**1) Does this way fully protect all of my PHP Source? (function.php, script1.php, script2.php, script3.php,...)**

**2) Does eval function works in ioncube or Zend Guard?**

Thanks.

Comment: The important question is **why** do you want to "protect" your PHP source? You're only obscuring it for yourself. If any users accessing your page sees your PHP then you need to fix the config of your webserver instead.

Comment: None of these methods will actually protect your source code - They are all trivially circumvented.

Comment: `echo simple_decrypt($text);`  Done.

Comment: I can just run the decrypt method and get your entire code.  So no, it is not secure.

Comment: In my experience, encrypting PHP software is not worth it: It is alreay protected by copyright laws and if you fear your client could be untrustworthy and steal your code he/she shouldn't be your client in the first place.

Comment: If you're already going through all the bother to set up and run ioncube or zendguard why do you want to write a half-assed encryption function? *Just use the thing you've just installed.*

Comment: Protect *from whom* exactly and *why*? Any security related question must specify a scenario, what should be protected from what.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat: "function.php" will be encrypted with ionCube And nobody can not guess the name of simple_decrypt function. is it right?

Comment: @Sammitch: I don't have the ioncube or zend Guard, but I can encrypt one file from "Online Encoder Service" with Very low cost :D

Comment: @Nils Werner: Unfortunately, in my country there is no copyright law!

Comment: @Alex if it doesn't require you to install a component on your server then it's only obfuscated and/or compiled to bytecode. *Still reversible*.

Comment: @RocketHazmat nailed it, but even if the decrypt routine isn't discovered or its name is unusable by being obfuscated (only a feature in the main ionCube product, not online), someone could easily make a one line patch to the C function that eval() uses internally to compile a string and expose the source there. Home brew solutions are generally the most flawed of all approaches.

Answer (score 0):

obscuring the code will only make development harder and increase cpu cycles (and thus slowing your script down). all code is reverse engineerable. you'de be better off just stating propper licenses and/or making code only available to developers

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like that in past to avoid reverse engineering. You can obfuscate all code with IonCube or zend Guard.
but your way, **eval=evil**...

There is a PHP implementation made on fully dotNet.
[Phalanger](http://www.php-compiler.net/)

I used on past, but simple things, but i heard good things about'it. Try it..

Comment: I want to run my script on linux server.